# How to add validation on a slot value in alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have a single intent in my skill **NoteMyDetail** which has three required slots: `name`, `age`, `gender`.
I have various utterances like *"note my details"*, *"note my name as {name}"* etc.
So if I say *"note my details"* it one by one asks for all the values and if I say *"note my name as Joe"* it asks for only the age and the gender.

Now the issue I am facing is how to add validations for these slots because when Alexa asks: *"what is your age"* and I reply my name is Joe or any gibberish it sends a "?" in the slot value.

How do I make sure that the value is a number only for age?

EDIT: So I used the code of the link: https://gist.github.com/stormbytes/7ee3a05aa03c0ada0621dde746f2a6f9#file-index-js-L31

I have the slots as required, so it asks for all the values and then checks for the value which disrupts the flow, so I made the slot values as not mandatory and checked if the value if defined/undefined. I am getting the following response in the simulator but it says "There was a problem with the requested skill's response"

```
{
"body": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "response": {
        "outputSpeech": {
            "type": "SSML",
            "ssml": "<speak> Sorry I did not get the age, please say it again </speak>"
        },
        "directives": [
            {
                "type": "Dialog.ElicitSlot",
                "slotToElicit": "ageValue"
            }
        ],
        "reprompt": {
            "outputSpeech": {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": "<speak> Please tell me your age </speak>"
            }
        },
        "shouldEndSession": false
    },
    "sessionAttributes": {},
    "userAgent": "ask-nodejs/1.0.25 Node/v6.10.3"
}
}
```

Comment: You can use **Confirmation**. If not, you can edit your lambda function to do the validations. Return a response like "it has to be a Number", and restart your skill.

Comment: I do not want to restart the skill as the user would have already added the values for the name etc and by restarting the skill, the user will have to enter the value for the name again.
Also, if its the third slot i.e. the gender then the name and age will need to be added again.
The reason why I can't use confirmation is because if the user says my name is Joe for the age slot and then confirms it. It will cause an issue as I want the age to be a number only

Comment: In that case you can use `Dialog.ElicitSlot` Directive. See this : https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#elicitslot . You can ask for `Age` as many times as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies @NikhilWagh.. but I am new to Alexa skill development, is there any example of the ElicitSlot as the link you sent explains what to do but not how to do it.

Comment: Which language are you using for your lambda function?

Comment: I found this link to check if the slot value exists or no: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/blob/master/handling-responses/slot-value-check/index.js

What should happen if the isSlotValid function does not return the value: I mean how do I use Dialog.ElicitSlot there, Also what if the Fallback intent gets called, how to maintain the already recieved slot values?

Comment: I am using Node js

Comment: See this : https://gist.github.com/stormbytes/7ee3a05aa03c0ada0621dde746f2a6f9#file-index-js-L31
If you want explanation, I can give you that.

Comment: @NikhilWagh Thanks for the link.. it is very usefull. I have updated the question as the comment has a character limit. Please check.

Comment: Why is the `slotToElicit : sugarlevel` , shouldn't it be `age`?

Comment: Sorry, it is ageValue (the slot name) that was my typo, but it is still giving the same results :(

Comment: Please check your `DeviceLog` in Alexa test simulator. You should be able to find `CaptureDebugger`. You might be able to find what exactly is going wrong. Since if you're getting this response, there should not be any error.

Comment: "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
"message": "The requested skill has not been configured to support dialogs yet. Please update the skill's configuration from the Developer Console"

.
.
.
.






Do we need to have atleast one required field for implementng the Dialog Directive because it was working when I had marked the slots as required?

Comment: No that's not true. Can you show me your `intentSchema`? Upload it to git, and paste a link.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Harshhb101/bcbf143d5817fa315dfd7088949f089d

Comment: Try adding this : https://gist.github.com/Nikhil-Wagh/651953fd201f02adbd19413bd526ee6a

Comment: nope, it gives the same error :(

Comment: Ok. Try making one of your slot as required, and then try. The response seems to be good, so only thing we can do is Trial and error.

Comment: Yes, if we have a slot (any slot) as required, it seems to be working fine. Also in the documentation, they have stated the requirements for using the Dialog Directive which states that you need to have required slots

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical case where you can use a recently released feature called [Slot Validation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/validate-slot-values.html). All you have to do is go to the page where you defined your slot as required and click on the `Validations` tab:

[image]

and add a validation rule. In your case where you're dealing with **age**, most probably and `AMAZON.Number`, you can set up two rules, one for the lower limit of the age (e.g. 0) and another one for the top limit (e.g. 100). Take a look at my example using a numeric slot called `ownedMiles`:

[image]

Once you do that anything that is not a number within the range defined by the validation rules will cause the provided prompt in the validation to be spoken and Alexa will try to collect the value again.